# Convert some SQL query to active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I have this "advanced" query (not much, really) and I would like to translate it into Ruby Active Record's syntax.

```
SELECT microposts.* 
FROM microposts
WHERE user_id IN 
      ( SELECT r.followed_id as uid 
        FROM relationships r 
        WHERE follower_id = 1 
      UNION 
        SELECT u.id as uid 
        FROM users as u 
        WHERE id = 1
      ) 
ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC
```

The idea was to retrieve all microposts for user 1 AND user 1 followed users in desc creation order, but I really don't know how to translate this easily using Active Record's syntax.

Any thought ?

PS : As asked here is some rails context :

I have 3 models : `Microposts`, `Users`, `Relationships`.

- Relationships is a join table handling all users relationships (follower/followed stuff).
- Users have many followed_users/followers through relationships.
- Users have many microhoops, and microhoops have one user.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the readability fix, ypercube :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is very specific, therefore your best bet would be to write a good portion of it using SQL, or try a gem like `squeel` that can help out generating very customized SQL from ActiveRecord.

Nevertheless, this should do the work with no additional gems :

```
user_id = ... #Get the user_id you want to test
Micropost.where("user_id IN 
  ( SELECT r.followed_id as uid 
    FROM relationships r 
    WHERE follower_id = ? )
  OR user_id = ?
  ", user_id, user_id).order("created_at desc")
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea about Ruby but the SQL can be simplified to:

```
SELECT microposts.* 
FROM microposts
WHERE user_id IN 
      ( SELECT r.followed_id as uid 
        FROM relationships r 
        WHERE follower_id = 1 
      ) 
   OR user_id = 1
ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer will assume *(since you've provided no ruby/rails-context outside of your raw SQL query)* you have a `User` model, a `Micropost` model through relation `:microposts`, and a `Relationship` model through relation `:following`. `User` has many `Micropost` and `Relationship` instances related. You could do

```
u = User.find(1)
user.microposts + user.following.microposts
```

or you could move this into a method within `Micropost`

```
def self.own_and_following(user)
  user.microposts + user.following.microposts      
end
```

And call `Micropost.own_and_following(User.find(1))`.

This may not be what you're looking for, but in given the above mentioned likely relations you have in your Rails application, it sounds like something similar to this should work.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I totally forgot about specifying my models and associations. But you are right, I'll correct it.

Comment: But this is not what I was looking for, as this will give me User's micropost and then all followed users microposts in order. I need all user's and user's followed users microposts ordred by date. A la twitter, facebook, etc in some way.

Comment: Does AREL convert `+` into UNION?

Comment: No, that's **[joining to arrays](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2B)**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using only where, seems a lot like a find_by_sql to me, and I don't know which one would be better :

```
Micropost.order('created_at DESC').
where('user_id in (select r.followed_id as uid from relationships as r where follower_id = ?) or user_id = ?', user.id, user.id)
```

Don't know how good this is, but it seem to be working.